# How to get latest record date from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to return the date and ID for the latest added record in on of our tables.
can anyone suggest right query for that plz. We are using sqlServer

```
SELECT [BGArx_ID], [BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE]      
FROM TECH_ARTICLES   
WHERE [BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE] = ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ORDER BY clause to sort by the newest record and then limit the query to return just one result.

```
SELECT BGArx_ID, BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE 
FROM TECH_ARTICLES 
ORDER BY BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**EDIT (marc_s)**
for SQL Server, which doesn't know the `LIMIT` keyword, you'd need to use `TOP 1` in the select instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 BGArx_ID, BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE 
FROM TECH_ARTICLES 
ORDER BY BGArx_PUBLISHED_DATE DESC
```